# Django filters "or"

Tags: django, orm, mptt

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_children')
  products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through="ProductTags", blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
  tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', through="ProductTags", blank=True)

tag_id in POST

currentTag = Tag.objects.get(id=tag_id)

childs = currentTag.get_children().filter(active=True)
```

should choose products that have a current tag or tags that are children of the current tag

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Q
products = Product.objects.filter(Q(tags = tag_id) | Q(tags__parent = tag_id))
```

should probably do the trick.